# Get specific object with specific class from HashMap (java)

Tags: java

I have a pack of bean class and rule class.

I'm trying right now to create a HashMap of my differents rules to have access of those different rules in other classes.

In TripleTriad.java (the class that manage my game) I have:

```
public static Map<RuleType, Rule> ruleList = new HashMap<>();

private void createRuleMap(Map<RuleType, Rule> ruleList) {
    ruleList.put(COMBO, new RuleCombo());
    ruleList.put(ELEMENTALE, new RuleElementales());
    ruleList.put(IDENTIQUE, new RuleIdentique());
    ruleList.put(MEMEMUR, new RuleMemeMur());
    ruleList.put(PLUS, new RulePlus());
}

public static Rule callRule(Map<RuleType, Rule> ruleMap, RuleType ruleType) {
    return ruleMap.get(ruleType);
}
```

I have an interface Rule (tried to use an interface but not sure of what I'm doing).

And then I have my different rules. For example:

```
public class RuleCombo implements Rule {
    public RuleCombo() {

    }

    public static void resolveRule(Tile tilePosee, FrameTT frame, Board board) {
        if (ruleExisting(IDENTIQUE)) {
            RuleIdentique.resolveRule(tilePosee, frame, board);
        }
        if (ruleExisting(PLUS)) {
            RulePlus.resolveRule(tilePosee, frame, board);
        }
        for (Direction direction : Direction.values()) {
            Tile tileDirection = getAdjacentTile(tilePosee, direction, board);
            if (checkTileExist(tileDirection)) {
                if ((tileDirection.getPlayer() != tilePosee.getPlayer()) && checkTileIsOccupied(tileDirection)) {
                    if (ruleExisting(ELEMENTALE)) {
                        RuleElementales.resolveRule(tilePosee, tileDirection, direction, frame, board);
                    } else {
                        cardPoseeWin(tilePosee, tileDirection, direction, frame, board);
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Actually the resolveRule() method is static, and it seems to not be that good. The thing is, every rule can call another rule.
That's why I try to use a HashMap and a static method to get my rule Object.

To use it properly I have to write:

```
RuleCombo ruleCombo = (RuleCombo) callRule(ruleList, COMBO);
ruleCombo.resolveRule(tileDirection, frame, board);
```

Is there a better way to write it?

Comment: Take a look into Chain of Responsibility pattern. It might be good fit in this situation.

Comment: Is `RuleType` an enum? Show us.

Answer (score 0):

Okay so I tried to get some info for chain of responsibility. I'm not sure but I think I get the idea. The thing is, with the kind of drawing I found, I still don't get how I can manage two methods calling each other. I have also a method calling itself (it works).
The only thing who can work by deleting the static flag is to put my rules object in argument but it's clearly not the solution.

RuleType is an enum, yes. Sorry I forgot to mention that...

```
public enum RuleType { IDENTIQUE, PLUS, COMBO, MEMEMUR, ELEMENTALE }
```

I think the whole rule part is a mess...
I just miss some basics knowledge. Maybe I don't need an interface, and every rule is an abstract class. In this case I don't have to create an object from it.